# Modern dance music?

Tags: modern-music

It seems dance, even social dance, and "high art" music once walked hand in hand (waltz, for example) but now have parted ways. Is this the case? The last major dance compositions I know of are the ballets of Stravinsky. Have any major composers since then written any modernist dance music, especially social dance music?

Comment: DJ Khaled and DJ Mustard have composed a number of dance tracks, so has a slew of other 'composers'.

Comment: Areel's answer points out the question: how modern is modern?

Comment: Anywhere from the 20th century on

Answer (score 1):

There was the flirtation with ragtime in the early 20th century, and Aaron Copland's 'cowboy' dances.